# How to implement maximum mean discrepancy (MMD) in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm doing some deep transfer learning studies and I need to add MMD as loss function to my Tensorflow model. Is there any available API in Tensorflow that can apply MMD as loss function directly?

If there is not, how can I implement it in Tensorflow so that the gradients can be applied automatically?

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/domain_adaptation/domain_separation/losses.py#L40